# How to do menu animation in SvelteJS?

Tags: svelte

I want to animate a "Hamburger" menu on click using svelte.

I want to use this menu animation on [codepen](https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop).

This is the javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

How will I do this in svelte?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same CSS, you need a variable for the open state, like:

```
 <script>
    let open = false

    function handleClick(){
        open = !open
    }
</script>
```

The html template can look like:

```
<div id="nav-icon1" class:open on:click={handleClick}>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

([Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/1e809195967e4daa816ecefbec00390d?version=3.12.1))